# WCF Rest Client sending incorrect content-type

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, coldfusion

I am trying to send a request using a wcf client to a ColdFusion 9 service using json.  However, the content-type of the request is for xml.

Here is the service contract.  As you can see we specificy using RequestFormat of json.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "ServiceAgreementRequestService", Namespace = NetworkNamespaces.ServiceNamespace)]
public interface IServiceAgreementRequestService
{
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(RequestFault))]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?method=CreateUser", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
CreateUserResponse CreateUser(CreateUserRequest request);
}
```

I have also tried to set the Request.ContentType on the OutGoing request and this also did not work.

```
using (var context = this.GetServiceClient(clientId))
{
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
var request = new CreateUserRequest(user.Id, user.Person.FirstName, user.Person.LastName);
var response = context.Channel.CreateUser(request);
}
```

Here is the request that gets sent

```
POST http://somesite.domain.com/WebServices/ProviderService.cfc/?method=CreateUser HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo7eh9U9jsBVLqVgGtqTK+eMBAAAAb++0xkOSQEmcAKZLgQEsp2/muY2ca6NJiul6pkAaWZwACQAA
Host: somehost.domain.com
Content-Length: 58
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

{"UserId":4,"FirstName":"FirstName","LastName":"LastName"}
```

How do I get this to use the correct content-type?

EDIT:

Under the hood, the GetServiceClient(clientId) call uses system.servicemodel.clientbase and ChannelFactory to create the communication channel.  The endpoint that we call out to changes by client so we have some code on top of those to dynamically change out the endpoint.

Some more info.  We have two applications : One is a .net MVC 4 web application to host the client app and one is a .net WCF Server application to host the backend services.  I can call out to the ColdFusion app successfully from the web application, but not the wcf Server application.  These both use the same code base to make the outgoing call.

As far as I can tell the config is the same for both.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="WcfRestBehavior">
<webHttp />
</behavior>

<client>
<endpoint name="ServiceAgreementRequestService" address="http://PLACEHOLDER/" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WcfRestBehavior" contract="IServiceAgreementRequestService"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the code on how the request is being sent? Setting the content-type to json of the outgoing response in the service returns the CreateUserResponse object in json format.

Comment: The second code snippet has the code for the sending the request.  This uses the System.ServiceModel to create the IClientChannel that is used to send the request.  All the work being done to construct and send the request is done by WCF.

Comment: Are you trying to perform a REST request. Does GetServiceClient exists in the proxy generated from wsdl. If you are using it then i guess you are trying to invoke the service using SOAP. In order to invoke the WCF service in RESTful way you would need to use HttpWebRequest class

Comment: Please see the below code sample to access a RESTful web service.

Comment: The following traces show in WCF : Sent Message Over Channel, Default Content type mapper selected the request format, 'xml', given the content-type, 'text/html'

Comment: We dont use the proxy generated code.  We created impelemented our (same principals, just built for our framework).  We originally implemented the service using soap, but then switched to rest hoping we could do that simply by decorating the contract and changing the config.  This works fine in some scenariors (calling from web project) but does not work from the WCF server project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the WCF REST Client within a service, you'll need to create a new operation context scope, by using code similar to the one below.

**Calling code:**

```
var client = this.GetServiceClient(clientId);
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{ 
    var request = new CreateUserRequest(user.Id, user.Person.FirstName, user.Person.LastName); 
    var response = client.CreateUser(request); 
}
```

**Other implementations**:

```
class MyType : ClientBase<IServiceClient>, IServiceClient
{
    public MyType() : base("ServiceAgreementRequestService") { }
    public CreateUserResponse CreateUser(CreateUserRequest req)
    {
        return this.Channel.CreateUser(req);
    }
}

public MyType GetServiceClient(int clientId)
{
    return new MyType();
}
```

Comment: This is basically what we are currenty doing. Our GetServiceClient method returns a clientbase.  and we use the channel to call the service method.  This does not work.  Here is another post where the user tried to do the same thing and works in a console app but not within another service call.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567589/wcf-service-calling-a-client-to-access-rest-using-json-is-not-giving-correct-c?rq=1

Comment: Are tou creating a new `OperationContextScope`, and making the request within that scope?

Comment: Your correct, I missed that.  Operation Context appears to have fixed my issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please find some sample code on how to invoke the WCF service using WebRequest

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = method;
            }

            if(method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
            {
                requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer(requestBody);
                request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);                    
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();                        
                    }
                }
                else
                {   
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }

    private static byte[] ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer<T>(T requestBody)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        var serializer1 = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));            
        var ms1 = new MemoryStream();            
        serializer1.WriteObject(ms1, requestBody);
        ms1.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(ms1);
        bytes = ms1.ToArray();
        return bytes;            
    }
```

Comment: So you can use the WCF framework to create services with all this stuff abstracted.  But to call the restful service you have to resort to doing all the work yourself?  That doesn't seem right and isn't really what I am seeing.  I can call a restful service and in one scenario, everything works fine.  In the other, the only issue is the content-type being set incorrectly.